# replace SNAPSHOT in pom.xml file jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, sed, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying replace to a snapshot version in a pom.xml in Jenkins file.

From:

```
<abc.version>123-SNAPSHOT</abc.version>
```

123-SNAPSHOT Could be any snapshot version.

To:

```
<abc.version>234-SNAPSHOT</abc.version>
```

I tried multiple commands which works fine in Mac OS but fails when I put them in Jenkins pipeline.

The generated command in the Jenkins log also works fine in Mac OS as is, but does not perform the replace.

Here are the few commands which I copied from Jenkins pipeline which works fine in Mac but does not perform replace in the jenkins pipeline itself.

**Escaped Command in Jenkins:**

```
sh "sed -i -e 's/\\<abc.version\\>[-[:alnum:]./]\\{1,\\}\\<\\/abc.version\\>/\\<abc.version\\>234-SNAPSHOT\\<\\/abc.version\\>/' services/spark-jobs/pcs/pom.xml"
```

**Command that is executed in jenkins pipeline:**

```
sed -i -e 's/\<abc.version\>[-[:alnum:]./]\{1,\}\<\/abc.version\>/\<abc.version\>234-SNAPSHOT\<\/abc.version\>/' services/spark-jobs/pcs/pom.xml
```

This does not replace the version in pom.xml

Any idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You can read pom.xml properties in Jenkinsfile directly by using a pipeline utility step by passing the

```
def pomModel = readMavenPom
def pomVersion = pomModel.getVersion().replace("123", "234")
```

Refer: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/

In case you want to rewrite the version in pom.xml, you can use mvn mojo

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=234-SNAPSHOT
```

This step rewrites the pom.xml file with the newer version 234-SNAPSHOT and old pom.xml is backed up as pom.xml.versionsBackup (include this wildcard in .gitignore, if you don't want to push it to git repo).